# Is there a way to find out what went wrong prior to a Windows Restore?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, system-restore

My Windows 10 desktop PC suddenly stopped booting to the Windows login screen and i had to restore it to a state from the previous day using Windows Restore.

Now everything works fine again, but I'm very curious to find out what caused those boot failures. Looking through Event Viewer doesn't help me much. Is there a way to find this information, maybe a log or something? Or is it completely lost due to Windows Restore?

Not sure if relevant, but the restore i did was just before upgrading my [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) installation to version 2.0.

Comment: Any log that did exist was lost when you performed the restoration.

Comment: @Ramhound: I see, so basically the answer to my question is "no", unless i try to force my computer into that faulty state which prevented the boot, which i'd rather not.

Answer (score 1):

**Boot log** may contain the information you need, if it was enabled.

You can enable it with the following steps:

1. Press **Windows + r** and type **msconfig.exe** and hit **ENTER**.
2. Click the **Boot** tab and check **Boot log**.

To access your boot log, open **`C:\Windows\ntbtlog.txt`** with Notepad or any text editor.

Comment: I see that my boot log option is disabled, and it's always been like that even before the restore. However i still have that ntbtlog.txt file in the Windows directory, so i don't know what to think. It seems to keep the log only for the latest boot, though.

Comment: Enable boot log and try to reproduce the situation, install the same software etc. Then check the log.